Clippy warning on documentation for macro invocations
I have the following rust benchmark code.
criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);

Clippy lint config in cargo.toml
[lints]
rust.missing_docs = "warn"

Upon running cargo clippy --workspace --all-targets
I have the following warning.
warning: missing documentation for a function
  --> benches/b.rs:13:1
   |
13 | criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


After adding documentation as suggested by lint.
/// doc
criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);

The warning persists.
warning: unused doc comment
  --> benches/b.rs:13:1
   |
13 | /// doc
   | ^^^^^^^ rustdoc does not generate documentation for macro invocations


I found out documenting macro invocation is different. But the one I am using is library provided.
How to make it work?

Unfortunately you cannot apply docs to a function created by a macro unless the macro author specifically adds support for it. However, you can at least scope turning off the missing docs warning by placing the criterion group in its own module.
#![deny(missing_docs)]
//! crate docs

use criterion::{criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};

fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {}

mod groups {
    #![allow(missing_docs)]
    use super::*;

    criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
}

criterion_main!(groups::benches);


You can't, but there is a workaround. Your macro invocations cargo expand to the following:
pub fn benches() {
    let mut criterion: ::criterion::Criterion<_> =
        ::criterion::Criterion::default().configure_from_args();
    criterion_benchmark(&mut criterion);
}
fn main() {
    benches();
    ::criterion::Criterion::default()
        .configure_from_args()
        .final_summary();
}

Here, the benches function is undocumented. Documentation adjacent to macro invocations does not document the function(s) they produce. I don't see way to cause your produced function to be documented (other than submitting a PR to criterion to add documentation support to the macro).
My recommendation is to insert #![allow(missing_docs)] at the top of your benchmark file(s) or module(s) to exempt them from the lint. If you want to comment your macro, you can use a normal comment, beginning with //.
